# How to configure ovirt Hosted Engine(ver-4.1.7) HA

Tags: ovirt

oVirt Hosted Engine HA (ver-4.1.7)-- I am new to oVirt, now testing latest ovirt setup. I have setup ovirt cluster using self hosted engine with two host. I am able to migrate the Hosted Engine vm by manually clicking on the migration tab, but if my Hosted Engine vm host suddenly goes down (e.g- power down) then the Hosted Engine vm is not migrating to another host. Also other vms on that host are not accessible. So I want to know what is the procedure of a self hosted engine HA configuration.

Answer (score 0):

in order to have a functioning HA Setup you have to setup the power management of your hosts. Very important is that both your hosts are able to run the self hosted engine. You should see a little grey or golden crown at you hosts overview in the ui.

It is necessary to configure host power management in order to utilize host high availability and virtual machine high availability.
From the documentation of oVirt: https://ovirt.org/documentation/admin-guide/chap-Hosts/